# "syntax error near expected token" using process substition

Tags: bash, shell, process-substitution

It's a bit of embarrassing question but i can not found the error. I am trying to do process substitution. Here is my code

```
while read compareFile1 <&3 && read compareFile2 <&4; do 
echo compareFile1
echo compareFile2
done 3< <(tail -n+4 test2.txt) 4< <(tail -n+4 test2.txt)
```

but the error is,

```
sh.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
sh.sh: line 7: `done 3< <(tail -n+4 test2.txt) 4< <(tail -n+4 test2.txt)
```

Any can help?

Comment: You're using bash-only syntax with `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process substitution is not an available feature in POSIX sh (`#!/bin/sh`, also invoked with `sh yourscript`); despite tagging this question "bash", you're clearly executing your script with a non-bash shell (or are otherwise entering portability mode, as with `set -o posix`).

Use bash instead; thus, putting `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of your script, or invoking it with `bash yourscript` if specifying an interpreter manually.

Comment: i think i am i am using bash because i am working in mac where bash is default

Comment: Whether your interactive shell is bash has no bearing on whether your *scripts* are also run in bash. What is the very first line of your script? Does it start with `#!/bin/sh`, `#!/bin/bash`, or something else? What command are you using to start that script? Are you running `./scriptname`, `sh scriptname`, `bash scriptname`, or something else?

Comment: ya, i understand my error, i was running the program by sh command and also there was no #!/bin/bash command at the starting of my file. Thanks for the eye opening.